# the right time to use coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

So basically I have a number of concerns holding me back from coffeescript:

1. I'm not really an expert in js yet, even though I'm using it for around 3 years now I still feel like I'm missing something important about it. Since it's mostly a supportive technology for me I never find time to go in depths of js ( which, I admit, might be a wrong attitude ).
2. My js knowledge will get even worse if I'll start Using coffeescript
3. I'm not sure if I can actually trust coffescript, meaning the js code it compiles to
4. At times I don't understand the js code coffeescript compiles to and even worse - why it compiles like that.

I'd like to know your thoughts on the above points. The crucial one is:
How using coffeescript affected your knowledge of js? And how important you think it is to fully understand js before switching to coffeescript?

Comment: The best question should be _"5. What coffee script gives us except of unreadable code"_!

Comment: If your work / potential work demand that you use coffeescript, then I guess go for it. Otherwise just go with normal js.

Comment: *"I'm not really an expert in js yet"* - then learn JS. go get a book and read. try [VaporJS](http://vaporjs.com/) while you are at it. why go through all the trouble using coffeescript?

Comment: It's the same as putting lipstick and wig and going to your parents telling them to please stop call you Vlad and now you are Valentina. OR me hating C++ so I'll just wrap it with synthetic sugar which makes it look like JS, cause I like JS syntax so much. the ridiculousness is infinite.

Comment: What's interesting is that we learned these lessons back in the 80s with C++. At first it was cfront that transpiled C++ into C. But it was a pain to debug. So people created native C++ compilers - gcc, cpp, etc. We're going through it again, though this time for a language that (in my opinion) is worse than the original. (I'd probably same the same about C++, but at least it introduced significant new functionality - whether benefits or not, I'll leave along - not syntactic sugar.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should understand what problems Coffeescript is supposed to solve.
And for that, you should have a basic knowledge of javascripts' "bad parts".
I suggest reading Douglas Crawford about that (there's a book, but also a lot of resorces on internet. Just google "javascript bad parts").
Basically, the idea is that "Underneath all those awkward braces and semicolons, JavaScript has always had a gorgeous object model at its heart. CoffeeScript is an attempt to expose the good parts of JavaScript in a simple way." (taken from coffeescript's site).

There's a tool to assist programmers to avoid javascript pitfalls called jslint.
This tool analizes your code and gives warnings about common mistakes, such as global variables, semicolon insertions, namespace pollution, etc...

Coffeescript translates to javascript. But the javascript it generates is a cannocical subset, highly compliant with jslint.
What's more, it generates javascript code valid on all browsers.
So it is not just a nice syntactic sugar layer, it really helps generate solid code.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to address your concerns.

1) If you've been using JS for three years, you probably have a pretty solid understanding of JS. If you haven't gained a solid understanding yet, it may be time to supplement your knowledge with one of the good JS books.

2) Coffee-script probably wont make your knowledge of JS worse. The way you design Coffee-script applications is the same way that you would design a JS application (for the most part), so the design skills you gain will transfer over. Program design, in my opinion, is the most important aspect of programming.

3) Why don't you trust the JS? Why do you trust any of the other compilers/interpreters/other tools you use? I doubt Coffee-script is bug free, but many people use it for many purposes. This means that a large set of behavior has been tested, often in production, so your use case has probably already been tried and tested.

4) Of course the JS generated by Coffee-script will look foreign to you, since the rules for generating it don't have human readability as a priority. Reading it, however, will increase your knowledge of JS as you see how peculiarly written programs run. This brings us back to point 1.

Comment: I voted your answer up, but I generally believe that human readability is actually a priority (maybe not the highest) of the CoffeeScript compiler design. I don't find that I need to look at the compiled JavaScript very often but when I do, I have no trouble connecting it to the intent of my CoffeeScript. That said, your point about reading it increases JavaScript knowledge is well made... as is the rest of your answer.

Comment: +1 as well here, but I don't agree with the foreign looking/not-readable point either. Coffeescript have very clear rules about how it translates to Javascript, and it is fairly easy to recognize the compiled code. The rules are right there, on the frontpage of http://coffeescript.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think that the crucial thing to remember here is that Coffeescript IS javascript. Every Coffeescript statement or magic operator has a distinct concrete representation in Javascript. For instance `(x) -> x * x` in Coffeescript will translate directly to `function (x) { return x * x; }`.

You can't really write Coffeescript without being aware of the Javascript it will generate. For one thing, the generated Javascript is what you will have to debug. If anything, I believe that writing Coffeescript could possibly improve your understanding of Javascript, because it forces you to make decisions that are unique to Javascript. For instance, when in Coffeescript, you decide to use `=>` instead of `->` in reality you are making a decision about whether or not you want to bind `this` - a very real Javascript problem.

When (or if) to start using Coffeescript? I think the answer to this is more or less up to you. Try it out, and if you feel that it is easier to get your tasks done using Coffeescript, then stick to it. If you find it difficult to write the code in a different language from the one that runs (and thus the one you have to debug), then go back to Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

So here's what I think about the topic:

1. JS is not a supportive technology (support for what?). It is a language mostly used on front-end and there is a new trend of using it on back-end. Since browser do not support CoffeeScript natively than unless you use it as a back-end then I don't think there is a point in using CoffeeScript. Although learning new language is always a good idea.
2. Not at all. Actually using CoffeeScript is like using different language. Learning one cannot make you dumber in the other. Unless you stop learning the other one.
3. There is no evidence that CoffeeScript compiles to buggy or slow code. Actually I am using CoffeeScript for some time and I didn't observe **any** performance hit.
4. Actually you don't need to understand **why** it compiles like this. If you are using CoffeeScript on back-end then you don't even have to look at the code it compiles into (you only need the source code). As for using it to make browser scripts then yes - it may be a bit difficult to work with it (debug). That's why I always advice to write *normal* JavaScript for browsers and use CoffeeScript on back-end.

Now as for the last question: I don't think that CoffeeScript affected my JS knowledge at all. I treat them as separate languages. Also you don't need to know JS in order to switch to CoffeeScript (although you should) unless you want to use CoffeeScript on front-end.

Also mastering JavaScript is **always** a good idea, no matter what. :)